# How far do I have to walk from London underground station to St Pancras international station?

Tags: public-transport, train-stations, tfl

How far do I have to walk from the London underground at St Pancras railway station to the St Pancras International to catch my train?

Comment: 5 minutes max you do.

Comment: Assuming you're going from the King's Cross underground station, it's a very easy walk.

Comment: Either of those comments could be answers.

Comment: Which line would you be arriving on? The distance from underground platform to Eurostar check-in varies widely depending on the line, and for some your *should not* follow the signs if you're in a hurry.

Comment: What is your destination by train? Four companies run trains from STP.

Comment: I'd also just like to add that some services to the North (in my case Bedford) are from platforms *upstairs* in the main terminal (platforms 1-4). Which is something I never expected and so missed my train by a few minutes. The signage is not easy to spot so hopefully this could help someone else being caught out as I was.

Answer (score 8):

**Kings Cross St. Pancras** underground station has exits directly into the St. Pancras International station complex.

The Eurostar departures area is in the part of the station that is closest to the Metropolitan/Circle/H&C line platforms.

Expect to walk 150-100 meters after you exit the Underground ticket hall. That's after up to 100-200 meters in corridors to get from the platform to the station exit, depending on which line you arrive on.  There's a diagram of the passages at https://tomhalltravel.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/king-cross-upgrade-map2.gif -- if you're arriving on one of the deep tube lines, first follow the signs towards the Circle Line until you're in a ticket hall, *then* exit through the ticket gates and follow signs towards St Pancras.

(For actually *catching your train*, remember that there's a check-in procedure and you may have to wait in line to pass the French immigration controls before you get to the platform. So walking is not going to be the main item in your time budget).

Comment: You are assuming that the OP is catching Eurostar but St Pancras International is the official name for the whole station so Jasmine could be going to take an East Midlands train, a South Eastern or a ThamesLink. Unlikely I know. +1 for your last paragraph for time checking in.

Comment: @mdewey: Hmm, you're right, it doesn't say in so many words. I concluded the OP is probably aiming for Eurostar because it looks like they think "St Pancras railway station" is distinct from "St Pancras International".

Answer (score 6):

The Kings Cross St Pancras underground station is linked directly to the St Pancras International train station, you won't see the light of day while going from one to the other.

If you arrive using the Circle, Metropolitan or Hammermith & City line, the station is just under the front of the station, and it's about 200 meters from underground platform to Eurostar check-in.

If you arrive using the Northern, Picadilly or Victoria lines, then those lines are pretty deep underground and it takes slightly longer (count 250-300 meters).

Also, the signage on some of those platforms now wants you to take the new route they added a few years ago, which is accessible, but much longer, as it brings you all the way to the "back" of the station, and it's probably closer to 500 meters to Eurostar check-in. It may make sense if you're not travelling by Eurostar but using one of the domestic services, though.